# Hyper-V connect to local computer throws an error - virtual machine management service

Tags: hyper-v

I am using Windows 10 professional, connected to office domain network.

I just enabled Hyper-V program with other related features in Windows Features.
[Hyper V and related program in Windows feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kebc1.png)

After reboot computer, I click [Connect to Server in Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFa09.png)

Then I got an error message: [related to Virtual Machine Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxRbT.png)
The message says:

> Hyper-V Manager "An error occurred while attempting to connect to server XX. Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server

I have googled everywhere, but there is no result. The closest post I could find is from this GitHub web link: [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/887).

Could anyone suggest how to solve this issue so I could begin using Hyper-V program?

Take note that I have switched my internet to a public WiFi and it still shows the same error message.

Update 01: [Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management is running in Services.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1HwT.png)

Update 02: My Hyper-V Manager version is 10.0.17763.1. My colleague managed to get his Hyper-V Manager working and his version is 10.0.17134.1

Comment: Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin, do you mean Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management in services.msc? If yes, I have started that service and still get the same error message.

Comment: Check the Windows event log for relevant errors.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, could you please suggest which activity in Windows Event Viewer should I look for?

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin should I then try google? Thanks Tips ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

Main reason behind this issue: Hyper-V Host Compute Service service fails to start with an error message quoted from Event Viewer:

> The Hyper-V Host Compute Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
>      The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

So I followed the steps in [Hyper-V Manager unable to connect to server "Local computer" solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/900298bd-4a86-4c9d-9950-11f0c050fa2f/hyperv-manager-unable-to-connect-to-server-quotlocal-computerquot?forum=win10itprovirt). Please ensure you run Powershell as an administrator.

After that, I manually start:

- Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management
- Hyper-V Host Computer Service

When I start Hyper-V Manager, I successfully connect to Local Computer.

Comment: Link Only Answers are frowned upon for good reason, links go dead. Please input details into answer.

Answer (score 1):

Steps from the link above [Hyper-V Manager unable to connect to server "Local computer"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/900298bd-4a86-4c9d-9950-11f0c050fa2f/hyperv-manager-unable-to-connect-to-server-quotlocal-computerquot?forum=win10itprovirt)

1. Open "Window Security"
2. Open "App & Browser control"
3. Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4. Switch to "Program settings" tab
5. Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6. Click "Edit"
7. Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
8. Start vmcompute from powershell
   net start vmcompute

Answer (score 1):

We recently had the same issue. Resolution was:

1. Open PowerShell as administrator
2. Execute `Set-ProcessMitigation -Name VMCompute.exe -disable CFG`
3. Reboot

Answer (score -1):

All you need to know about setting up Hyper V Server Manager on a workgroup Client. Part  3
https://youtu.be/BVcmIhxZCLw

Comment: link only answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).